# epsilon delta to prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{1}{f(x)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

i was solving problems on my textbook.... and i became stuck.
The question is: Let $a\in (- \infty , \infty ).$ Suppose  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=L \neq 0$. Use the  $\epsilon - \delta$ arguement to prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} \frac{1}{f(x)} = \frac{1}{L}$.

So i know that i have to show that $ \forall  \epsilon >0, \exists  \delta >0$ s.t. if $0< | x-a | < \delta$ , then  $|  \frac{1}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{L}  | < \epsilon $.

$|  \frac{L-f(x)}{f(x)L} | =|  \frac{-(f(x)-L)}{f(x)L}| = |  \frac{f(x)-L}{f(x)L}  |  $

now i'm stuck.. i guess i'm supposed to use $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon $ from the condition above. But i don't get what i'm supposed to do with |f(x)L| to ensure that it isn't too small.

I didn't tag this as homework because this isn't.

Comment: why do you think $\delta(x)$ for $f(x)$ would work for $\frac{1}{f(x)}$?

Answer (score 1):

For $\epsilon=\frac12|L|$ you will have $\frac12|L|=\epsilon>|f(x)-L|>|L|-|f(x)|$ that gives $|f(x)|>\frac12|L|$

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle\left|\frac{1}{f(x)}-\frac{1}{L}\right|=\frac{1}{|L|}\frac{1}{|f(x)|}|f(x)-L|$$

Taking $\epsilon=\frac{|L|}{2}$ we have
$$|f(x)-L|<\frac{|L|}{2}$$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$.

Rearranging and using the triangle inequality we find that $$\frac{1}{f(x)}<\frac{2}{|L|}$$

There is also $\delta_2>0$ such that
$$|f(x)-L|<\frac{|L|^2}{2}\varepsilon$$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta_2$

Now just combine these facts.

Comment: Where did you get  $|f(x)-L |< \frac{|L |^2}{2} \epsilon $?

Answer (score 0):

Let  $h(x)=f(x)/L$ (this is possible since $L\not= 0$), so  $h(x)\to 1$ as $x\to a$ by the product law, and we will show that $1/h(x)\to 1$ as $x\to a$. Thus

$$\bigg|\frac{1}{h(x)}-1\bigg| =\frac{|h(x)-1|}{|h(x)|}$$

Given $\varepsilon>0$, we  choose $\delta>0$ such that $|h(x)-1|< \varepsilon/2$ and  $|h(x)-1|<1/2$ are satisfied  whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$. The second of these inequalities give us $h(x)>1/2$. Thus

$$\frac{|h(x)-1|}{|h(x)|}< 2|h(x)-1|< \varepsilon$$

as desired. Hence $1/h(x)\to 1$ as $x\to a$ but this means $L/f(x)\to 1$ as $x\to a$, and then $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{1}{L}\frac{L}{f(x)} =\frac{1}{L}\lim_{x\to a}\frac{L}{f(x)}=\frac{1}{L}$$

as was to be shown.